# How to enable Memchecker (Valgrind) with openmpi (finding paths)

Tags: debugging, gcc, parallel-processing, mpi, valgrind

From here: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/openmpi/faq/?category=debugging#memchecker_how

I'm using GCC. I need to get my path to openmpi and valgrind. However, I cannot find them on my own PC nor on the cluster I'm working with.

On my own laptop:
I've echo'd out my PATH variable but it's not there. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

On the cluster: I've echo'd out the $PATH variable and found this: "/opt/gridware/mpi/gcc/openmpi/1.6/bin" - I guess this is what I need in place of "/path/to/openmpi". But how do I find where valgrind is? I can't find that in the path, nor do I know where to look.

Edit: I've found the location of openmpi and valgrind with the "whereis" command. In the modelling software I'm building, there is a "configure" file. So when I run:

`./configure --prefix=/opt/gridware/mpi/gcc/openmpi/1.6/bin/ --enable-debug \
 --enable-memchecker --with-valgrind=/usr/bin/valgrind`

I get:
`configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-debug, --enable-memchecker, --with-valgrind`

Is this not the configure file I'm meant to use?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is valgrind installed on that cluster? Have you talked to the admins? Do you need to load the appropriate module (in case the cluster uses lmod or alike). Is valgrind installed on your laptop?

Comment: Yes, Valgrind is installed on the cluster on the login node, which we use to compile our programs. I've sent an email to the admins a day ago, still no reply yet.

On the cluster: $ gcc --version gcc (GCC) 4.8.2

valgrind-3.8.1

On my laptop:

gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

valgrind-3.10.1

So it should work, I have above the required versions.

Comment: Oh, I've found it with "whereis valgrind".

However, now I'm confused about the "configure" part. The numerical modelling library I'm building has a configure file in it. But when I run the commands:

 ./configure --prefix=/opt/gridware/mpi/gcc/openmpi/1.6/bin/ --enable-debug --enable-memchecker --with-valgrind=/usr/bin/valgrind

I get
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-debug, --enable-memchecker, --with-valgrind


Is this not the configure file I'm meant to use?